# Explain materials with 4-fold symmetry having same reflectance when shone with LCP and RCP

Tags: symmetry, spectroscopy, polarization, chirality

This is my first post here.

I am currently reading "Optical planar chiral metamaterial designs for strong circular dichroism and polarization rotation" by Do-Hoon Kwon, Pingjuan L. Werner, and Douglas H. Werner.

This paragraph mentions that

"Strong circular dichroism
For maximum CD, the fitness to be maximized is defined as

f =|A+−A−|=|T+−T−|, (1)

where A± are the absorbances for the RCP and LCP incident waves, which are given by A ± = 1−R± −T±. The second equality in (1) follows from R+ = R−, which can be obtained from the reciprocity theorem for structures having four-fold rotational symmetry and a normally incident plane wave [7]."

Can somebody explain to me what the reciprocity theorem is, and how it affects the reflectance of structures with 4-fold symmetry.